# What term describes a phrase like "in English, please"?

Tags: terminology, context

The phrase "in English, please" has different meanings in different social contexts. In one context it might mean literal English language, and in another it could imply a response in layman's terms.

I recall a scene from Star Trek, which humorously shows contextual confusion:

> Kirk:  (in battle) *Status, Mister Spock.*
> Spock: *Captain, the deflector field ionic beam is over-critical.*
> Kirk:  *English, Mr. Spock.*
> Spock: *Am I not using the correct form of the English language?*
> Kirk:  *Spock!*
> Spock: *Our shields will be down in ten seconds.*

Comment: You'd say it could be used both literally and metaphorically/figuratively. But this is true of almost all figurative expressions and most literal expressions. [This question is similar but I don't think it's quite the same](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224074/is-there-a-name-for-this-an-idiom-that-ambiguously-refers-to-itself).

Comment: It's irony here, pretending the original was not English for being so technical.

Comment: [This question on alternative terms for a double entendre suggests "equivocality"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17042/alternative-to-double-entendre) although that's certainly not a common word.

Comment: Almost any term can be used literally and nonliterally. It is not clear what you think is special about the literal/nonliteral distinction in this case.

Comment: A request for clarification or simplification?

Comment: As you say, it depends on the social context. In some contexts it's literal, in others it's sarcastic or metaphorical.

Comment: One could say it's synecdoche, using 'English' to mean a subset, 'everyday English'. But there's more involved here: a play on words with humour and a mild reproof  (one could argue that Spock is using grammatical language but violating the Gricean maxim of clear communication to non-precisionists).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't think the question is about this specific phrase, but the general concept of a phrase having two very different meanings depending on context. But as Stuart says, this is so normal that there isn't really a term for it.

Comment: It comes across as a typically British or more narrowly English expression of irony or even sarcasm.

Comment: @Barmar The general term is the same as for different senses of a word: << **polysemy** [noun] [LINGUISTICS]:
the coexistence of many possible meanings for a word or phrase. >> [Oxford Languages; courtesy of Google] This makes the question a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a name for a pair of words or phrase that can have a double meaning?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215886/is-there-a-name-for-a-pair-of-words-or-phrase-that-can-have-a-double-meaning) Often, context will disambiguate, as with polysemous words. // Oxford Languages, above, must be using the mathematical sense of 'many' (more than 1).

Comment: Thank you all for your thoughts, upvoted you all. I think polysemy is it, with the word English appearing ambiguous as both a noun and implied transitive verb (?). Am now curious about the role repetition plays in conversation involving polysemy (e.g. Kirk repeats the ask, or the skit _Who's on First_). @EdwinAshworth your comment "_Perhaps to 'Australian' is to use bottom-spin_" turned my day right-side up :D. Feel free to throw out an answer, though I'm unsure it's possible after close.

Comment: While *polysemy* **could** be used here, that label seems more useful when the meanings do not overlap, and neither is merely a narrower version of the other. In this case, *English* is used in a way that simply narrows down its default, literal meaning to something like: English that is readily understood by average English speakers.